# how to solve the circulating in nested serializers in django rest API?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write nested serializers but it shows KeyError:

i wrote serializers like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU047.png)

i wrote models like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQqJF.png)

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serializers as is if they are defined in the same file or import them if they come from other modules.
As all your models seems to be in the same module, you could put all your serializers in the same file. For example:

```py
from another_module.serializers import TestSerializer

class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'


class ApplicantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job = JobSerializer(many=True)
    test = TestSerializer()  # Just here as an example

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicantProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```